# Three real roots of equation is the length of three sides of a right triangle, find the parameter

Tags: cubics

Three real roots of the equation $x^3-2p(p+1)x^2+(p^4+4p^3-1)x-3p^3=0$ is the length of three sides of a right triangle, what is the value of $p$?

Comment: Ok, ignore my previous comment -- it works out. If you do it correctly (as I didn't at first), you'll get $p = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The condition $p = \sqrt{2}$ is a necessary condition. But then I still get no solutions for $a,b,c$ (since they have to be positive). Perhaps I made a mistake?

Comment: @quasi $p=\sqrt{2}$ gives the roots $1,\,2\sqrt{2},\,3\,$ which do indeed form a right triangle.

Comment: Yes, I simplified incorrectly -- $1,2\sqrt{2},3$ works, and is the only such triangle.The algebra is messy.

Comment: @quasi The *other* real values $p=0,\,-\sqrt{2}\,$ lead to ineligible roots, however, so your point about having to actually verify the solutions is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $a,b,c$ be the roots, then by Vieta's relations:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c^2 &= (a+b+c)^2 - 2(ab+bc+ca) \\
 &= \left(2p(p+1)\right)^2 - 2(p^4+4p^3-1) \\
 &= 4p^2(p^2+\bcancel{2p}+1) - 2p^4-\bcancel{8p^3}+2 \\
 &= 2(p^4 + 2p^2+1) \\
 &= 2(p^2+1)^2
\end{align}
$$

For the roots to be the sides of a right triangle, one of them, say $a\,$, must satisfy $a^2=b^2+c^2$.

Comment: Then $a=p^2+1$, and substitute it to the equation, simplify, got $2p^5-3p^3-2p=p(2p^2+1)(p^2-2)=0$, then $p=\sqrt{2}$. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Ycoronene Right, and glad it helped. As noted in a comment, you need to also verify (and reject) the other potential real solutions $p=0$ ($a,b,c$ then form a degenerate triangle) and $p=-\sqrt{2}$ (one root is negative), leaving $p=\sqrt{2}\,$ which gives *the* eligible triplet $a,b,c\,$.

Comment: Yes, From the Vieta's formula, $abc=3p^3>0$, so $p>0$. Thanks again!